# Dump() object to JSON pretty-print string

Tags: c#, json, wcf

Ok, I am having a bit of a problem with this, and I would rather not build my own code if there is an applicable one with permissive license..

I need a way to dump instance of object, any object, into human readable JSON string. Our plan was to use ServiceStack.Text but that piece of software has a restrictive license in v3, and we are not building a FOSS. I also have zero understanding from mgmt about buying commercial license for ServiceStack v4 just to dump objects. So we need something along the lines of MIT licensing.

Internal JSON serializer in WCF seems to only work with DataContract adorned objects.

Any idea if something like that is available?

Comment: Use JSON.NET ? if you can use 3rd party DLLs that is.

Comment: Perfect... Thanks. We can use 3rd party, as long as the license is permissive for commercial use.

Comment: Ok, works like a charm. Can you post an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [JSON.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to convert an object to a JSON String.

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objectToSerialize);
```

I also do the following to Format the JSON nicely into a readable file (instead of all just one line)

```
JToken jt = JToken.Parse(json);
string formattedJson = jt.ToString();
```

Comment: won't I get the same thing with `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(instance, Formatting.Indented);`?

Answer (score 5):

Using Newtonsoft.Json also we can achieve the same with

```
    string formattedJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, Formatting.Indented);
    Console.WriteLine(formattedJson);
```

Answer (score 3):

After and including .Net Core 3.1, we don't need to use `Newtonsoft.Json`. Instead, built-in [`System.Text.Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/how-to?pivots=dotnet-core-3-1) can be used.

```
string jsonString = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(yourobject);
Console.WriteLine(jsonString);
```